# How to Hide UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When pressing a button in my view controller it shows a `UIView` which has `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController` and `UITableView` in it(changes the view's hidden property to NO).
When I select a row in the table view I set the view's property to `hidden=YES`, but it doesn't hide the tableView. What can be the problem?

I implemented the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and I receive  `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message(I set the view's `hidden=YES`  there).

Please note that when I call view's `hidden=YES` from `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` it hides successfully.

I think that `UISearchDisplayController` is causing the problem.

Some code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.searchView.hidden = YES; // hide successfully the tableView.
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    self.searchView.hidden = YES; //doesn't hide the tableView.
}
```

EDIT: Found the problem, see my answer below. In short I added `[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];`

Comment: You can add or remove the table view from main view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - I needed to add `[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];` and now it works.

Code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO]; //Added line of code.
    self.searchView.hidden = YES; // Now it works!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 tableview.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score -2):

[self.yourview setHidden:Yes];

if the tableview is inside the view it should also hide